# Использование слайсов в JS

Tags: javascript

Есть ли возможность в JS использовать слайсы в таком кейсе:

```
substr = str[index:]
```

как это можно делать в Python'е. Или же, если есть другие более *удобные* аналоги `substr()` - подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Нет, нету, только методы. Впрочем, никто не мешает запилить плагин для Babel и прикрутить эту фичу.

Comment: @Other, спасибо)

Comment: [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: @Grundy, да, но slice не позволяет не указывать второй индекс.

Comment: @Grundy, извините, проверил. Кажется, работает))

Comment: @isnullxbh, собственно, в моем комментарии ссылка на документацию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ближайший аналог на JS - `slice`

```js
const str = 'example';
console.log(str.slice(0,2)); // 'ex'
console.log(str.slice(4)); // 'ple'
console.log(str.slice(-2)); // 'le'
console.log(str.slice(1,-1)); // 'xampl'
```